# New Analytics code not sending hits

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I recently implemented the new gtag.js Analytics code on some sites. None are receiving hits. I do a 'Send Test Data' from the Analytics tracking info screen and no Real-Time hits come in. It's been a few days since I implemented the new code and nothing seems to work. Here is the code I am using:

```
<!-- Global Site Tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-47914920-3"></script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'UA-47914920-3');
</script>
```

I have it right after the opening `<head>` tag.

I have used 2 Chrome extensios (Tag Assistant and Google Analytics Debug) to confirm that the code is working. But nothing comes into Analytics.

Any ideas what I can do to get my data coming in again?

Comment: Does the domain you setup in the Google Analytics dashboard match the URI of the page where the code is executed?

Comment: Also; why are you using gtag? It is deprecated.  You should be using analytics.js: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/

Comment: yes, the domain matches the URI of the page. I am using gtag because it is the one that is listed in the Tracking Code section of our Analytics account. I will try this other one. Thank you

Comment: I replaced the gtag code with the analytics.js code. Now using this code: `<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-47914920-3', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->`
Still not pulling in hits though.

Comment: gtag is not deprecated it's actually the newest version of the tracking code. @DerekBrown must be thinking about ga.js that was deprecated.

Comment: @Eduardo Thanks for the info. I was wondering why they would have deprecated code on their Tracking Info screen. Any ideas why ours is not pulling in hits?

Comment: Do you see the hits being fired in Tag Assistant? If you record events with it, you can view a more detailed report about what got fired and where it was sent.